# SUM based on age range and gender

Tags: mysql

I have to write a query to get the value based on age and gender in SQL.

```
create Table aggr_notify (age int, gender VARCHAR(20), total_notified int);
INSERT INTO `aggr_notify` (`age`,`gender`,`total_notified`) VALUES 21,female,230);
INSERT INTO `aggr_notify` (`age`,`gender`,`total_notified`) VALUES 1,male,20);
INSERT INTO `aggr_notify` (`age`,`gender`,`total_notified`) VALUES 55,female,200);
INSERT INTO `aggr_notify` (`age`,`gender`,`total_notified`) VALUES 34,male,30);
INSERT INTO `aggr_notify` (`age`,`gender`,`total_notified`) VALUES 64,male,10);
INSERT INTO `aggr_notify` (`age`,`gender`,`total_notified`) VALUES 89,female,77);
```

My sample data is

[image]

My sample output is like

```
age  | Male   | Female
0-15   5000     1000
16-30  4000     2000
31-45  2500     3000
46-60  2000     3440
>60    2990     2345
```

I have to sum the total notified column based on both age and gender. 
I've tried but it doesn't seem to be working. Any idea on how to write the query to get my estimated output data.
My sample query:

```
select sum(case when gender in ('male','female') and (age >= 0 and age <= 15) THEN total_notified ELSE 0 END ) as '0-15',
 sum(case when gender in ('male','female') and (age >= 16 and age <= 30) THEN total_notified ELSE 0 END ) as '16-30', 
 sum(case when gender in ('male','female') and (age >= 31 and age <= 45) THEN total_notified ELSE 0 END ) as '31-45', 
 sum(case when gender in ('male','female') and (age >= 46 and age <= 60) THEN total_notified ELSE 0 END ) as '46-60',
 sum(case when gender in ('male','female') and (age >= 61) THEN total_notified ELSE 0 END ) as '>60' from
  aggr_notify;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: show us what you tried at least.

Comment: Replace sample data screenshot with CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO script. Show desired output strongly for shown source data.

Comment: I've added create query but my insert query is loading CSV file to my database. @Akina

Comment: *but my insert query* Make it by hands - sample only needed. 5-10 records - it's not too hard. And you ignore that shown output MUST match sample data. *I've added create query* Edit, delete fields which are not related to your question.

Comment: *`case when gender in ('male','female')`* ??? There are some another genders in your data?

Comment: I've added some sample data check it out. @Akina

Comment: Yeah we have transgender also. @Akina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schematically:

```
SELECT CONCAT(MIN(age), '-', MAX(age)) ages,
       SUM(total_notified * (gender = 'male')) total_male,
       SUM(total_notified * (gender = 'female')) total_female
FROM phase_two.aggr_notify
GROUP BY CASE WHEN age BETWEEN  0 AND 15 THEN 1
              WHEN age BETWEEN 16 AND 30 THEN 2
              WHEN age BETWEEN 31 AND 45 THEN 3
              WHEN age BETWEEN 46 AND 60 THEN 4
              ELSE                            5 
              END;
```

> I've added some sample data

Look for

```
SELECT CASE WHEN age BETWEEN  0 AND 15 THEN 1
            WHEN age BETWEEN 16 AND 30 THEN 2
            WHEN age BETWEEN 31 AND 45 THEN 3
            WHEN age BETWEEN 46 AND 60 THEN 4
            ELSE                            5 
            END group_number,
       CONCAT(MIN(age), '-', MAX(age)) real_ages,
       SUM(total_notified * (gender = 'male')) total_male,
       SUM(total_notified * (gender = 'female')) total_female
FROM aggr_notify
GROUP BY group_number
ORDER BY group_number;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=79a608eee0a45cc8de308266a3923ca6)

Comment: @pilcrow Look, maybe it will be more interesting? Additionally - I recommend to create static table with ages groups ranges and join it into the query.

Comment: Yeah, that's good. Can't upvote you twice. :)  You could also do _SELECT CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 0 AND 15 THEN '0-15' ..._ to get group_names rather than group_numbers.

Comment: @pilcrow Yes, you may - but using a table with pre-defined names and ranges is more safe I think...

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your time :) @Akina